# How to implement progress bars in C like apt-get?

Tags: c, linux, progress-bar, apt, tqdm

I want to inplement a progress bar use C like tqdm in Python or apt-get in Ubuntu. But I have no idea.

**My problem is how to make the progress bar always be at the bottom of the terminal, and the top normally outputs something else.**

Like the apt-get program in Ubuntu is implemented in the following figure.
[image]

Comment: That is done with terminal-specific character sequences. They are often called escape sequence. You don't want to implement this without a library (such as ncurses). There are so many terminals that it's better to trust on the work that those library builders have done for you.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't state my question clearly. I only want to use language c to achieve this effect. It's better that there is a library could achieve this effect. Thank you for your comments. I will look at the ncurses library. @Cheatah

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you are simply trying to find only the progress bar within the apt or apt-get code, so you can make use of it later, then there is no guarantee that it is named Progress:, or that the prompt containing Progress: is even in the script you are searching. It is likely sourced from another file.

You can try opening the script in an editor like vim or kwrite or jot, etc. and looking within the script for where the meter is called and go from there. There is no telling whether it will be under scale, meter, percent, etc...

In the absence of finding anything, you can always use something simple. There are many available on the web. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

## string of characters for meter (60 - good for 120 char width)
str='▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒'

tput civis                  # make cursor invisible

for i in `seq 1 100`; do    # for 1 to 100, save cursor, restore, output, restore
    printf "\033[s\033[u Progress: %s %3d %% \033[u" "${str:0:$(((i+1)/2))}" "$i"
    sleep 0.1               # small delay
done

printf "\033[K"             # clear to end-of-line

tput cnorm                  # restore cursor to normal

exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I want to know how implement by using C. Or is there a c library could achieve this effect. @Nasyx Rakeeb

Comment: You can try to use tqdm library. You can look at their source code and see how it's implemented. I think they use the best practices in this subject: tqdm on github

Note that there also exists other libraries in python and other languages so you can check them out as well.

Answer (score 0):

I made it in the form of a macro for direct use.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define START_PROGRESS_BAR(pbar, len) \
    char __##pbar[len] = {0};         \
    memset(__##pbar, '#', sizeof(__##pbar) - 1)

#define PROGRESS_BAR_RUNING(pbar, per, fmt, ...) ({                                       \
    float p = per >= 100.0 ? 100.0 : per;                                                 \
    int left = (p / 100.0) * (sizeof(__##pbar) - 1);                                      \
    int right = (sizeof(__##pbar) - 1) - left;                                            \
    printf("\r[%.*s%*s] %.0f%%" fmt, left, __##pbar, right, "", (float)per, __VA_ARGS__); \
})

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    START_PROGRESS_BAR(mybar, 64);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        PROGRESS_BAR_RUNING(mybar, (float)i / 31 * 100.0, " %d KB/s", 105);
        usleep(100000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```